# Java - How to convert string to xml whitout doc

Tags: java, xml, get

I need to make a get request in a server to get information. I ask to have this information in xml and my problem here is that I am trying to keep this answer as an xml object. 
I found a lot of answers but only to create documents, not to only have object (I need to say that I am not allowed to create a file on my client side).

I have this code right now:

```
    URL url;
    String urlForScores = urlToRead+"format=xml";  
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    String line;
    String result = "";
    try {
       url = new URL(urlForScores);
       conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

       readerChannel = new BufferedReader(
                              new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
       while ((line = readerChannel.readLine()) != null) {
          result += line;
       }
       readerChannel.close();



       JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(String.class);
       Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
       StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(result));
       JAXBElement<String> je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlSource, String.class);
       System.out.println(je.getValue());

    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can you help me please ??

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To use the JAXB marshaller you should be using the JAXB annotations. I'm sure that java.lang.String is not annotated with anything. You have to actually model your classes based on the XML structure and annotate them with the JAXB annotations and then you can use the JAXB marshaller to unmarshall the string.

Comment: How should I do to only get my xml from the response of the request in the server if the InputStream is not suffisiant ?

Answer (score 0):

Using JAXB as in your example requires you to build an Object structure that is exactly as the data from the XML file you receive. If you don't have the XML schema for automatically building the JAXB classes this can get complicated.

Therefore building a Document is much simpler and you don't need to save anything to a file for this solution:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dc = parser.parse(conn.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I tried but it is sending me a fatal error :2:6 The target of the treatment instruction corresponding to "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed

Comment: I print it out and get this: 
<?xml version="1.0"?><records><record><rank>1</rank><name>nini</name><score>120</score><timestamp></timestamp></record><record><rank>1</rank><name>lulu</name><score>120</score><timestamp>160</timestamp></record></records>

Comment: I found the answer, it was a space in my server file. I took it of and that worked ! 

Thank you for your help